# Odd GPU / CPU throttling behavior in WinToGo-Pro 10

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, throttling, cpu-throttling

I have two *identical* Dell Precision 5530 work machines (8850H / Quadro P1000). They are running the exact same OS (win10 enterprise) with the same exact power configuration and both of their bioses have been reset to factory settings.

On one of the laptops, if I run Furmark - maxing out the gpu - and run p95 with 4 threads, the GPU will never downclock/throttle and rather the CPU throttles to ~1 ghz (~40% of its base clock). If I run the exact same workload on the other laptop, the CPU is able to maintain the base clock and the GPU throttles instead. This seems likes VRM throttling as the GPU and CPU are nowhere near their max temp.

It seems that regardless, either the gpu or cpu will throttle. However what determines which will throttle and how could this be changed?

Comment: Swap the hard drives. Does the problem move? If so, then it's in WinToGo-10 Pro.

Comment: Windows 10 Professional, does not officially support the creation of `Windows To Go` instances, so that might be part of your problem (Only Enterprise can create Windows To Go instances).  If I am not mistaken Microsoft actually recently discontinued the creation of Windows To Go instances even in Enterprise due to poor performance with the drives. So I suspect your performance problems are directly connected to the fact you are running Windows To Go in an unsupported configuration.

Comment: I reinstalled win10 enterprise on both of them to the SSD and the problem still persists. (Edited the question above)

Comment: When you say they're identical, do you mean that they share the exact same configuration parameters, such as pagefile size, power options and the like? Do their respective video drivers share the same version too?

Comment: For both I reset bios to factory settings and reinstalled Windows 10 Enterprise. As for drivers, I didn't install any (just let Windows automatically pull in one).

Comment: Have to checked the Bi-directional prochot? It means that one chip can throttle, because of the other. You can try to modify it using ThrottleStop.